# SQL Server 2008 / 2012 [time] multiple ins & outs- advanced query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with raw data, wherein a particular id can have multiple time entries for each day, it's not static, but it will be in pairs, if there is an in entry, then there will also be an out entry as below:

```
Row_Num Tr_Date     Tr_Time    Machine_Serial   Machine_ID  ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------
75251   04/05/2014  7:31:56 AM  243496             71767    8525
75259   04/05/2014  8:14:21 AM  243512             71767    8525
75265   04/05/2014  9:07:21 AM  244005             73330    8525
75312   04/05/2014  9:29:09 AM  244115             71767    8525
75465   04/05/2014  1:01:45 PM  244658             71767    8525
75985   04/05/2014  5:34:30 PM  245501             73330    8525
```

I want to mark each row with 'START' and 'END' according to the pair.

The first time should be 'START' , second time should be 'END', then third time should be 'START' and fourth time should be 'END', it goes on like this. As I said before there is no predefined set.

Kindly help on the query.

Thanks and regards,

Desired result:

```
Row_Num Tr_Date      Tr_Time    Machine_Serial  Machine_ID  ID      Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
75251   04/05/2014  7:31:56 AM  243496             71767    8525    START
75259   04/05/2014  8:14:21 AM  243512             71767    8525    END
75265   04/05/2014  9:07:21 AM  244005             73330    8525    START
75312   04/05/2014  9:29:09 AM  244115             71767    8525    END
75465   04/05/2014  1:01:45 PM  244658             71767    8525    START
75985   04/05/2014  5:34:30 PM  245501             73330    8525    END
```

Comment: Could you add a desired result? I'm a bit confused which id (machine_id or id) you're talking about that you want to pair up on.

Comment: Same result as above but with new column in the end with 'START' and 'END'  values according to the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), and just output the status depending on whether it's even or odd;

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY row_num) % 2 = 0 
  THEN 'END' ELSE 'START' END type
FROM mytable
ORDER BY row_num;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33850/6).

(of course you could also calculate the row number over tr_date and tr_time, but in this case the row_num field seems sufficient)

Comment: i need to mark it 'start' and 'end' irrespective of machine_id

Comment: I need the output to be as follows: `Row_Num Tr_Date Tr_Time Machine_Serial Machine_ID ID Type
75251 04/05/2014 7:31:56 AM 243496 71767 8525 START
75259 04/05/2014 8:14:21 AM 243512 71767 8525 END
75265 04/05/2014 9:07:21 AM 244005 73330 8525 START
75312 04/05/2014 9:29:09 AM 244115 71767 8525 END
75465 04/05/2014 1:01:45 PM 244658 71767 8525 START
75985 04/05/2014 5:34:30 PM 245501 73330 8525 END`

Comment: that table got messed up, to be clear, same data like the above table with additional column with 'START' and 'END' values.

Comment: @user3625561 Updated the answer slightly with the correct naming.

Comment: This is really a poor schema you should really have a bit column to identify each record whether its a start time of end time. After you have entered all the data and than guessing based on the order of Row_Num column is very error prone, Imagine something goes wrong and an entry is missed your whole data is corrupted, Seriously you should consider adding a BIT Fields to mark rows as Start or END.

Comment: @M.Ali, thanks for your comment but if i would had a bit column already specifying the start and end, then i would not have come here to ask for help. I need to add that 'start' and 'end'. pls. help me.

Comment: @user3625561 What part of the answer above is not working for you?

Comment: It gives 'START' for all rows: I'm using the following query:  `SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY userpin, trdate, time1 ORDER BY userpin, trdate, time1) % 2 = 0 
  THEN 'STOP' ELSE 'START' END status
FROM [ABCD].[dbo].[MA_DATA] WHERE Tr_Type=55 AND USERPIN=8525
ORDER BY USERPIN, trdate, time1 ;`

Comment: 'tr_type' '55' is for successful entry, 'userpin' is same like 'id'. Each date can have multiple time entries.

Comment: @user3625561 You should partition by fields that should give you separate series, and you don't want a separate series to start every time the time changes. What you _probably_ want is something like `SELECT *, CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userpin ORDER BY trdate, time1) % 2 = 0    THEN 'STOP' ELSE 'START' END status FROM [ABCD].[dbo].[MA_DATA] WHERE Tr_Type=55 AND USERPIN=8525 ORDER BY USERPIN, trdate, time1`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, i added trdate to the partition with userpin and it looks like i got needed results, but have to cross verify the data. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the query worked well and I have verified the data by many ways, it is perfect. Thank you very much for the help.